# Server tape backup solutions?

Tags: windows, backup, tape, tapedrive

Our server is now setup to run a basic Domain. Our other (older) samba server uses an Iomega Internal REV tape drive for backups.

There is an advantage to installing another tape drive the same into the new server, making the ability to mix and match the media. The disadvantage may well be that the rev drive is an old way of doing things.

My question is: if we are going to pay around £200 for a new Iomega internal REV drive, is there any newer technology that would be more of an advantage and outweigh the fact that we already have REV media.

I'm thinking of advantages like half the backup time etc. The function of the drive would be daily backups where we can simply insert the disk and everything gets backed up, then one copy would be sent off site with a director every night in case of any loss or damage to the site.

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: At least it's not a ZIP disk.  Ugh

Comment: Haha, I have luckily not had much experience with ZIP disks. Although I used to think the disks looked cool in comparison to floppy disks. I was about 9 years old though.

Comment: REV isn't tape - they're disks.

Comment: Your are, of course, correct! I should have said "Internal REV disk drive". Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup to portable disk - ideally an eSATA one rather than USB - it'll be much faster than tape, I would imagine cheaper too, if you go for a two disk mirrored box then it'll be pretty reliable too.

Comment: Will the built in Server 2003 backup solution allow for an exact duplication to an esata drive?

Answer (score 4):

Just a note: In my opinion, sending your backups home with an employee (director or otherwise) is not an appropriate solution for storing and protecting your backups.

What if the director has an emergency and isn't available when you need one of the backups?

What if their house burns down? (heaven forbid)

What if they lose one or more of the backups?

What if they're let go or quit, and it's a less than amicable split?

My suggestion is to find an appropriate offsite storage service that fits your budget.

Comment: Hi Joe, there are three backup disks done on a daily basis - the first remains on site, the other two are taken home with two directors. The issue I can forsee with offsite storage is the dropoff and collection of the daily disks. Once a disk is taken home overnight, it's then brought back in the morning to be updated.